# datasource connection, erro ao subir JBoss

Tags: java, sql-server, conexão, jboss

Eu estou tentando fazer uma conexão de fonte de dados no JBoss, mas sem sucesso.

Eu vi [este tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration) para criar a minha conexão.

Então ocorreu o erro:

> ConfigurationPersistenceException: Failed to parse configuration" Eu tentei outros tutoriais, mas em todos eles eu recebo o mesmo erro: "ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration

Eu pesquisei mas não encontrei a causa do erro; alguém pode ajudar-me?

Erro:

```
17:51:35,411 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:266) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Duplicate attribute 'pool-name'. at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [349,146]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:606)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:479)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:464)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.AttributeCollector.throwDupAttr(AttributeCollector.java:1143)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.AttributeCollector.resolveNamespaces(AttributeCollector.java:997)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.InputElementStack.resolveAndValidateElement(InputElementStack.java:498)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2942)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2802)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1050)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1125)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:152) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.nextElement(ParseUtils.java:52) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.nextElement(ParseUtils.java:68) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:343) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 3 more
```

Standalone.xml:

```
    <!--
  ~ JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source.
  ~ Copyright 2011, Red Hat, Inc., and individual contributors
  ~ as indicated by the @author tags. See the copyright.txt file in the
  ~ distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
  ~
  ~ This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
  ~ under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
  ~ published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of
  ~ the License, or (at your option) any later version.
  ~
  ~ This software is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  ~ MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
  ~ Lesser General Public License for more details.
  ~
  ~ You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
  ~ License along with this software; if not, write to the Free
  ~ Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
  ~ 02110-1301 USA, or see the FSF site: http://www.fsf.org.
  -->

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.0">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.web" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld" />
    </extensions>

    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="PropertiesMgmtSecurityRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" />
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <management-interfaces>
           <native-interface interface="management" port="9999" />
           <http-interface interface="management" port="8081"/>
        </management-interfaces>
    </management>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>

            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>

            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>

            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="H2DS">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <pool></pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.0">
            <deployment-scanner scan-interval="5000" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" path="deployments" />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.1" lite="true">
            <!-- EJB3 pools -->
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5"
                                     instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>

            <!-- Session bean configurations -->
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
            </session-bean>

        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.0" default-cache-container="hibernate">
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.0">
            <archive-validation enabled="false" />
            <bean-validation enabled="false" />
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads blocking="true">
                        <core-threads count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
                        <queue-length count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
                        <max-threads count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
                        <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads blocking="true">
                        <core-threads count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
                        <queue-length count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
                        <max-threads count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
                        <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.0">
            <jmx-connector registry-binding="jmx-connector-registry" server-binding="jmx-connector-server" />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.0">
            <jpa default-datasource=""/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.0" activation="lazy">
            <configuration pid="org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager">
                <property name="manager.root">jboss-osgi</property>
            </configuration>
            <properties>
                <!--
                    A comma seperated list of module identifiers. Each system module
                    is added as a dependency to the OSGi framework module. The packages
                    from these system modules can be made visible as framework system packages.
                    http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA
                -->
                <property name="org.jboss.osgi.system.modules">
                org.apache.commons.logging,
                org.apache.log4j,
                org.jboss.as.osgi,
                org.slf4j,
                </property>
                <!--
                    Framework environment property identifying extra packages which the system bundle
                    must export from the current execution environment
                -->
                <property name="org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra">
                org.apache.commons.logging;version=1.1.1,
                org.apache.log4j;version=1.2,
                org.jboss.as.osgi.service;version=7.0,
                org.jboss.osgi.deployment.interceptor;version=1.0,
                org.jboss.osgi.spi.capability;version=1.0,
                org.jboss.osgi.spi.util;version=1.0,
                org.jboss.osgi.testing;version=1.0,
                org.jboss.osgi.vfs;version=1.0,
                org.slf4j;version=1.5.10,
                </property>
                <!-- Specifies the beginning start level of the framework -->
                <property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">1</property>
            </properties>
            <modules>
                <!-- modules registered with the OSGi layer on startup -->
                <module identifier="javaee.api"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.logging"/>
                <!-- bundles installed on startup -->
                <module identifier="org.apache.aries.util"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.webconsole"/>
                <module identifier="org.osgi.compendium"/>
                <!-- bundles started in startlevel 1 -->
                <module identifier="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>
                <module identifier="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                <!-- bundles started in startlevel 2 -->
                <module identifier="org.apache.aries.jmx" startlevel="2"/>
                <module identifier="org.apache.felix.eventadmin" startlevel="2"/>
                <module identifier="org.apache.felix.metatype" startlevel="2"/>
                <module identifier="org.apache.felix.scr" startlevel="2"/>
                <module identifier="org.apache.felix.webconsole" startlevel="2"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.jmx" startlevel="2"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.http" startlevel="2"/>
                <!-- bundles started in startlevel 3 -->
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.blueprint" startlevel="3"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.webapp" startlevel="3"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.xerces" startlevel="3"/>
            </modules>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.0">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Disabled" flag="required"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.0">
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid />
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0" default-virtual-server="default-host">
            <connector name="http" scheme="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
               <alias name="localhost" />
               <alias name="example.com" />
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0" />
    </profile>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
           <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public">
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8087"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="jmx-connector-registry" interface="management" port="1090"/>
        <socket-binding name="jmx-connector-server" interface="management" port="1091"/>
        <socket-binding name="jndi" port="1099"/>
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    </socket-binding-group>



    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PNDS" pool-name="DS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://CX:1433;databaseName=DS_des</connection-url>
            <driver>sqlserver</driver>
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>true</prefill>
            </pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>us</user-name>
                <password>mo</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>

        <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft">
            <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.sqljdbc4</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </datasources>


</server>
```

module:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.sqljdbc4">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="sqljdbc4-4.0.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: Poste o arquivo standalone.xml  completo. Após postar, me avise por favor.

Comment: postei só essa parte, pq o erro ocorre na primeira tag desse trecho do xml, o erro ocorre na tag "<datasources>"

Comment: Concordo, eu pedi para postar completo para te falar as linhas exatas onde está o erro.

Comment: postei ele completo

Comment: Comenta o <datasources> no final do arquivo e tenta novamente.

Comment: ja fiz esse teste se tirar o datasources e tudo o q tem dentro dele o Jboss sobe normalmente, ams se tirar apenas a tag "<datasources></datasources>" e deixar a configuração interna ocorre o msm erro, porem na linha "<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PNDS" pool-name="DS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">"